# Neo4j Cypher Query to Get User Feed

Tags: neo4j, cypher, feed

Assume that my project is Facebook. I want to display a feed which consists of my status updates and my friends' status updates both.

Here are the relations;

- User KNOWS user
- User UPDATES_STATUS status

This is how I get my friends status updates;

```
START me = node(1) MATCH me-[:KNOWS]-()-[:UPDATES_STATUS]->friendsStatusUpdates RETURN friendsStatusUpdates
```

And this is how I get my own status updates;

```
START me = node(1) MATCH me-[:UPDATES_STATUS]->myStatusUpdates RETURN myStatusUpdates
```

Both queries work fine but I need a single query that combines these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I got from [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/2nEp8i9J2jk);

```
START me = node(1) MATCH me-[:KNOWS*0..1]-()-[:UPDATES_STATUS]->statusUpdate RETURN DISTINCT statusUpdate
```

Only thing I had to do was adding `*0..1` depth indicator to the relation in order to get both 0 or 1 level depth results.

Edit: I had to add `DISTINCT` because without it query includes 0 level nodes 2 times which results in duplicates.

---

Alternative query which returns same results using `WITH` statement;

```
START me = node(1) 
MATCH me-[:KNOWS*0..1]-friend
WITH DISTINCT friend
MATCH friend-[:UPDATES_STATUS]->statusUpdate 
RETURN DISTINCT statusUpdate
```

Comment: Your queries only returns posts from a users's friend how it gives posts of user himself in  this case (me) ???????

Answer (score 0):

Crate a himself relationship between user node to itself than query is START me = node(1) MATCH me-[:KNOWS|HIMSELF]-()-[:UPDATES_STATUS]->friendsStatusUpdates RETURN friendsStatusUpdates

Comment: i'm not sure whether creating a multigraph is a good standard solution in neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/introduction-pattern.html

```
START me = node(1) 
MATCH me-[:UPDATES_STATUS*1..2|KNOWS]-myStatusUpdates 
RETURN myStatusUpdates
```

in case the `*1..2` wont work with `|` command, do this:

```
START me = node(1) 
MATCH friendsStatusUpdates2-[?:UPDATES_STATUS]-me-[:KNOWS]-()-[:UPDATES_STATUS]->friendsStatusUpdates 
RETURN distinct myStatusUpdates,friendsStatusUpdates2
```

just edit the `RETURN` statement with some aggregation function so you will get one status per row